# "search results" within favorites page goes back to regular search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Possible bug, Steps to reproduce:

1. add at least 4 favorites
2. click the link that says **view all favorites...** found on the right hand side of the jobs tab.
3. click one of those favorites.
4. once you are on that company page favorite click the link at the top left that states **search results**

This returns you back to your regular search results, not your favorite search results.  Instead of seeing 4 jobs, you see 2308 jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed and pushed to prod build. Thanks for the report!